# Python: Invalid literal for int() with base 10 when inputting value to be converted

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer, user-input, invalidoperationexception

This is my code, the issue comes from the fourth block of my code, first and second line, I tried alternatives, mentioned them above the code in english and attached an errors pic.
It's a school assignment and I'm not understanding the reason of the issue. The code is very simple to understand, if you need any further information I'll answer as soon as I see the message.

THANK YOU for the time you'll be taking to help me find a solution,
Sincerely,
Rouba

I finally found the solution, it was I mistake I made, the code is running perfectly fine. But I'm keeping this post in case some newbie makes the same mistake, the answer is in the comments.

```
    #################################
    # Ex5 : Autorisation d’accès
    # 20205793 
    # Créé le 09/03/2021
    #################################
```

id_saisi = input("Identifiant:")

```
 #Note au correcteur: Veuillez excuser l'absence d'accents, mon clavier est un qwerty et c'est assez couteux de mon temps de devoir switcher entre qwerty et azerty

    import stdiomask 
#importe le module stdiomask qui permet de remplacer la valeur saisie par des etoiles

    def Authentification(id_valide,pass_valide):

#fonction Authentification qui prend 2 parametres
   

     print("Veuillez saisir votre identifiant:")
        id_saisi = input("Identifiant:")
        print("Veuillez saisir votre mot de passe:")
        pass_saisi = stdiomask.getpass("Mot de passe:")

#emploi du module stdiomask
#masque le mot de passe entré en le remplacant par des etoiles
#demande a l'utilisateur son identifiant et son mot de passe

`#I tried id_saisi=int(float(str(id_saisi[12:]))) but returns error couldn't convert string to float`
`#also tried id_saisi=int(id_saisi[12:].strip('"')) returns same error as if I didn't strip the quotes`
   

     id_saisi=int(id_saisi[12:])
     pass_saisi=int(pass_saisi[12:])

    if id_saisi == id_valide & pass_saisi == pass_valide :
        print("Votre identifiant et votre mot de passe sont valides")
#alerte l'utilisateur que ses id et mots de passe sont incorrects
   

     elif id_saisi == id_valide & pass_saisi != pass_valide:
        print("Votre mot de passe est invalide")
#alerte  l'utilisateur que son mpt de passe est incorrect

    elif id_saisi != id_valide & pass_saisi == pass_valide:
        
    
    print("Votre identifiant est invalide")

#alerte l'utilisateur que son id est incorrect
   

     else:
            print("Votre identifiant et votre mot de passe sont invalides")

#verification de la validite du mot de passe et de l'identifiant et affichage d'une message en fonction de chaque cas

        
    Authentification(20205793, 2002)

#les valeurs valides sont définies lors de l'appel de la fonction
```

Comment: I don't think the error is in the string conversion. Just convert `id_saisi` and `pass_saisi` to int as is and change the `&` in your if-else statements to `and`

Comment: Yes but that's not what I need to do, I need to take only the numeral part of these variables to be able to compare them to the valid values entered as parameters of the function. And so I was looking for a way to strip only the part input by the user which is the numeral part but since the parameters are integers I have to convert the input to be able to compare it to the parameters of my function. Since it's an assignment the structure of the program isn't very flexible, I have to reach a certain goal following certain steps but the structure is optional as long as I follow the steps.

Comment: I see, so in short the inputs need to be stripped of anything non-numeric? Are you allowed to use regex? Also, which lines are the only parts that you are allowed to modify?

Comment: Oh no, this isn't the main goal of the exercice, the goal is very simple but I was complicating my life trying to use "Identifiant" inside the parenthesis of input() when I don't even know how to use it correctly. That's what led me to my mistake. I didn't know the value actually being stored in the variable was only the user's input. Thank you for your help !!! I kinda had to figure out the solution but my question and your answer made me realize my mistake, thank you, really.

Comment: No problem, when in doubt just print the outputs where you see something wrong. Good luck on your exercise

Comment: Yea I tried to do that and didn't understand why the output was empty, I was so confused that I decided to post this question, I didn't know where the mistake actually was but now it's all cristal clear. Thank you !! Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that in the string there is at least one character that is not a digit and the string cant be converted to int or float.

two simple ways to validate that are to catch the exception thrown by the casting or to check the input is all digits.

exception catching:

```
try:
    id_saisi=int(id_saisi[12:])
except ValueError:
    print ('input is not a number')
```

isdigit:

```
if id_saisi[12:].isdigit():
    id_saisi=int(id_saisi[12:])
else:
    print ('input is not a number')
```

Comment: Oh indeed the input isn't a number, it's an empty variable. Thank you so muchhhhh Sir Salman. I just figured out that the problem was actually me thinking the value of the variable id_saisi was "Identifiant:user input" when it only was the user's input. So what I was doing was wrong since the beginning, I should just convert the variables as Jsandesu said, thank you both.